# Laravel 7.x - How to remove 'public' from URL?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-7

Stuck with this for a long time. I found similar questions but none of the answers are working for me!
.htaccess in root folder looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Why don'[ you use the default Laravel htaccess file ?https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess

Comment: @KarlHill I tried the default file but still doesn't work!
Do I have to change the htaccess file in the public folder too ?

Answer (score 18):

Create a file named as '.htaccess' in root and add the below code. That's it

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

Comment: It worked in laravel 8.x version. Thank you.

Comment: It worked in Laravel 9. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The example [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess) is in the /public directory. You will also need to configure you're server correctly and have it look only at the /public directory instead of root. You shouldn't need an .htaccess file in the root.

You will need a httpd-vhosts.conf with something like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName yourapp.com
    ServiceAlias www.yourapp.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/yourapp/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Notice this line:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/yourapp/public
```

You can read more about Laravel webserver configuration [here.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#web-server-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

inside of your main .htaccess it should read:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on     
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

replace the existing " RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] " if something like this exist.

Answer (score 0):

below solution worked for me.

Create .htaccess file in root directory and place code something like below.
copy server.php file and paste it in root directory with named as index.php .

### put below code in .htacess created file in root directory .

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```