# Remove 'public' from laravel 7.x on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, url, laravel-7

I researched about this problem and found many solutions, but could not find a solution to the problem which arise after editing .htaccess file. Here is my problem. I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61806001/laravel-7-x-how-to-remove-public-from-url) for removing 'public' from URL of my laravel website and it works fine. However, when I open my website with 'public' at the end of base URL, it also opens up the same page. As far as I know, it's a bad thing from the SEO's point of view.
I want my site to be opened only with the base URL and not with 'public' at the end of the base URL. My website is on shared hosting. How can I achieve that?

This is how my .htaccess file looks right now -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Ashish, good that you have shown your efforts, keep it up. Could you please do mention from which url to which url you want to redirect/rewrite for better understanding of question please.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461322/upload-laravel-5-to-server-subfolder/35474800#35474800. Default .htaccess that comes with Laravel need not be changed

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I wanted to open my site only with base url like 'mysite.com' and not like 'mysite.com/public'. I was able to fix it with the help of Donkamash's answer. Thanks Donakamash for help. However I did not create a separate folder for containing the laravel root files. I simply placed the root files one level above the 'public_html' folder and now my site does not open with 'public' at the end of URL.